# Wrapping foreach result in a div

Tags: php, html

I have this function working great

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories(array(
    'hide_empty'      => 0,
    'taxonomy'        => 'category',
    'orderby'         => 'title',
    'order'           => 'ASC'
));
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $firstletter = strtoupper(substr($category->name,0,1));
    $link = get_category_link( $category->term_id );
    if ($firstletter != $current) {
        $postlist .= "<b><a name='$firstletter'> $firstletter </a></b><br>\n";
        $nav .= "<a href='#$firstletter'> $firstletter </a> ";
        $current = $firstletter;
    }
    $postlist .= "<a href='$link'>" . $category->cat_name . "</a><br>\n";
}

print $nav . "<br>" . $postlist;
?>
```

What I need, is to wrap the entire list starting with the letter. For example, Letter M will be wrapped in a div with all the categories starting with M.

This is what I currently get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPqkv.png - Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be on the right path.  I think this is what you are requesting to do:

```
$closeLastDiv = false;
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $firstletter = strtoupper(substr($category->name,0,1));
    $link = get_category_link( $category->term_id );
    if ($firstletter != $current) {
        if ($firstletter == ""){ //first time through
            $postlist .= "<div>";
            $closeLastDiv = true;
        } else {
            $postlist .= "</div><div>";
        }
        $postlist .= "<b><a name='$firstletter'> $firstletter </a></b><br>\n";
        $nav .= "<a href='#$firstletter'> $firstletter </a> ";
        $current = $firstletter;
    }
    $postlist .= "<a href='$link'>" . $category->cat_name . "</a><br>\n";
}

if ($closeLastDiv) {
    $postlist .= "</div>";
}
```

Comment: $firstletter look like never take the value ""

Answer (score 0):

All you need is comparte the current letter with before letter, and if changed print the starting wrapper + content. When the letter changes, close the wrapper and open the next wraper.

Something like this:

```
$current = "-";
$postlist .= "<div>";

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $firstletter = strtoupper(substr($category->name,0,1));
    $link = get_category_link( $category->term_id );
    if ($firstletter != $current) {
        $postlist .= "</div><div id='{$firstletter}'>";
        $postlist .= "<b><a name='{$firstletter}'>".$firstletter."</a></b><br>\n";
        $nav .= "<a href='#{$firstletter}'>".$firstletter."</a> ";
        $current = $firstletter;
    }
    $postlist .= "<a href='$link'>" . $category->cat_name . "</a><br>";
}
$postlist .= "</div>";
```

The first div remain empty, but all other are ok.

Comment: Thank you, that worked as well. But, it created an empty <div></div> on top of the list.

Screen: http://i.imgur.com/Z1P4JLs.png

Comment: Well, this is an example of use. You can use this empty div to put a title or something else. Or maybe if you want more clear aproach you need to reverse the condition in the if statment, and be sure the last loop of foreach to close de div wrapper.